# Extremely slow wifi, wired connection is fine (OSMC)

Tags: networking, wifi

I'm having issues with my wifi speed on my Pi 2 with the current osmc alpha build. The wired network connection is totally fine, I'm getting maximum download speeds with that.

I have made one speedtest within the local network and one by downloading a file from the web. Both with ridiculously slow speeds.

Local:

[image]

Remote:

[image]

Is there any setting I could check? I have tried 2 different wifi modules, both work well on my raspberry pi 1 running RaspBMC.

I'm afraid it might be some kind of bug in the current osmc build. I decided to choose osmc because it seems like the current raspbmc isn't compatible with the Pi 2.

Comment: What does sudo iwconfig report?

Comment: here's the result: http://pastebin.com/xWJLaWeY

Comment: Try sudo iwconfig which reports link speed and quality.

Comment: bash: iwconfig: command not found :-(

Answer (score 3):

If you're using one of those itty-bitty Wifi dongles that barely protrudes from the USB socket, you will find that they have a very limited range (i.e. feet) because they just don't have room internally for a good antenna.  I have one that I bought from Adafruit which is 802.11n capable, but typically gets only around 150-200kb/sec sitting just 4 or 5 feet away on the desk from the Wifi router.  However, if I just touch my finger to the metal shield of the dongle, my body becomes enough of an antenna that the download speed will go up to well over 1MB/sec in most cases.  There are better dongles that include external antennas, and you would likely get much better throughput that way.

Comment: But why does it work then on a Raspberry Pi 1?

Comment: I have a similar problem I was streaming HD video on Rasbpian install with this Wifi dongle, was getting 20**mb**its, no problemo, i then reinstall, now i only get... 31.7**kb**it for no reason at all. Exactly same image, same SD card, using wicd-curses, same power supply. Very strange and annoying!

Comment: I support @andy. Those thumb wifi dongles don't need much to drop connection speeds.  The Pi in a different angle, a chair, a television or an extra laptop could be a reason your signal is below par.

Answer (score 0):

This always happens with *wifi*, *Wifi* is a signal, like your TV dish outside. And could be disrupted on the way to where your pi is. When using **ethernet**, it gives a direct connection without any disruptions. So its best to use **ethernet**.

Comment: Yes, I have already switched to ethernet. But I would like to understand, why the wifi didn't work. Ethernet is so stationary, I wanna be able to use the pi for things like attaching it to an AR-Drone and stuff like that.

Comment: It is quite odd though... I don't understand how wifi wouldn't work.